# IBM DB2 on Cloud - Missing "Result Set" tab when running a SQL statement

Tags: sql, db2, set, cloud

Wondering if you can help me. I am using IBM DB2 on Cloud, and running an SQL statement, for instance creating a table.
Unfortunately, the "Result Set" tab is not displayed in the SQL Editor, only the Log tab.
Without the Result Set tab I am not able to see the outcome when running the sql statement. Any idea how I can make the tab "Result Set" being displayed?
Much appreciate it
Romeo

Comment: What kind of result set do you expect from CREATE TABLE? Only SELECT statements and (some) stored procedures can return a result set.

Comment: Thanks mustaccio. The issue is occurring also with Select statement. The tab is missing.

Comment: You can try by accessing https://console.bluemix.net/dashboard/apps, create an free account. Click on the Catalog menu item, scroll down to the section for
Databases, and click on the tile for Db2 service. [Make sure you choose “Db2”. Do NOT choose “Db2 Warehouse” or “Db2 Hosted” or “SQL
Query”.]. When you create a DB2 service, open it, Open Console and from Menu "Run SQL". thanks a lot

Comment: I have good news. Yesterday did not work. Tried again today, and after running SELECT * FROM INSTRUCTOR query, the Result Set was displayed. Mystery solved. Thanks a lot.